# Postgres insert with select and values

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

So I'm trying to insert a value into a secondary table, get the returned id from the insert, and use it together with some values in a prepared statement I'm writing.The return of the first statement(table2) is an id for a foreign key column in the first table.
 I want to get the id of table 1 in the end.Something like :

```
WITH table2ID AS
(
INSERT INTO table2 (value) VALUES ('somevalue') RETURNING id;
)
INSERT INTO table1(table2returnvalue,othervalue) VALUES
(table2ID 'val2') RETURNING id
```

I can see that I will probably need a transaction as well, because I don't want an isolated in table2 if table1's statement fails for some reason.

Could you please help?

Comment: What exactly is your question? A single statement (and that's what you have) is **always** atomic. It either succeeds completely or fails completely.

Comment: As I specified I'm trying to use the return value from an earlier insert as a value for the next insert statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) its usually easiest to return the entire row (output from table2) and reference that in your second insert query.

```
WITH table2 AS
(
    INSERT INTO table2 ( value )
    VALUES ( 'somevalue' )
    RETURNING table2.*;
)
INSERT INTO table1 ( table2returnvalue, othervalue )
SELECT table2.id, 'val2'
FROM table2
RETURNING table1.id
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
WITH table2ID AS
(
  INSERT INTO table2 (value) VALUES ('somevalue') RETURNING id;
)
INSERT INTO table1(table2returnvalue,othervalue) 
SELECT table2ID.id, 'val2' FROM table2ID;
```